# How can I delete a row in a table

Tags: php, sql

How can I delete a row in a table using PHP and MYSQL? with account_name, maintenance_type, ma_status, ma_contract_start, ma_contract_end, ma_reference_no

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM a_table WHERE account_name="someaccountname" AND maintenance_type="whatever"   etc...
```

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html
- http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqldelete.php

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you looking for a tutorial here take a look at this

http://w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM account_name WHERE SomeField='value'");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```